# What is the difference between shared folder and synced folder in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

While going through Vagrant tutorials, I have seen two options for sharing folders between host and guest machines - shared folders and synced folders. What are the difference between them?

Or, is synced folder the new name for shared folder, in Vagrant 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Shared Folders` is more VirtualBox specific (`vboxsf`) and have known performance issues as number of files grows.

Vagrant v2 (For vagrant 1.1.x and 1.2.x) [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html) use a more generic name Synced Folder, which includes the default `vboxsf` and NFS.

In addition to `vboxsf` and NFS, `sshfs` is also worth looking into if your host is running Linux.

Comment: I can't stress the "have known performance issues" topic. Especially when you host is Windows, this can really become an issue.

Comment: @mark: But the vagrant documentation states that NFS is not supported on Windows...

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, synced folder is the new, more generic name for a feature that is not only VirtualBox specific anymore as of Vagrant 1.1.