# How to setup remote debugging in PyCharm on Windows with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, pycharm

I have been able to setup Vagrant on Windows 7 64-bit for a django project. The Vagrant instance is running the application with postgres as backend. I have setup port forwarding, so I am able to access through my browser on local machine. I have also setup remote interpreter in PyCharm. But, I am unable to figure out how to open the project, which is on vagrant instance, in PyCharm 3.0. I also have the source code on my local machine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Synced Folders](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) may be something you are looking for.

NOTE: by default Vagrant use VirtualBox's `vboxsf` for synced folder and share your project directory (where the `Vagrantfile` resides) to `/vagrant` within the guest.

However, vboxsf has known performance issues with large number of files and directories. You can try to move the project to `/vagrant` (or whatever synced folder) so that both the host (Windows 7) and guest can access the project easily.  See if it works well. If you see slowness try moving to `NFS` or `sshfs`.

Reference

- [Vagrant shared and synced folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528717/vagrant-shared-and-synced-folders)
- [What is the difference between shared folder and synced folder in Vagrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816806/what-is-the-difference-between-shared-folder-and-synced-folder-in-vagrant)